# What is the most efficient way to find numbers within a string of other characters?

Tags: c, linux, string, algorithm, parsing

String of 3 numbers of any length - embedded in spaces and tabs, represented below with the `\t` marker:

```
123456789 \t 12345 \t6789\n
```

There can be any amount and combination of space and tab' between the numbers.

For example, this is also valid:

```
1    \t \t2\t\t\t\t\t \n3\n
```

What is the most efficient way to extract the 3 numbers ?

Looking at [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) but seems the exact format of the string is needed, is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: this is good, please put in answer

Comment: I actually like the existing one a lot more. Much more to the point and extensible.

Comment: Removed the confusing `''` sequences since code markup makes actual spaces obvious.

Comment: @paxdiablo: ok, cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious/simplest is `sscanf`:

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", &v1, &v2, &v3) == 3) {
    /* extracted 3 numbers successfully */
```

The `%d` format specifier skips whitespace (which include `\t` and `\n` characters), so the variable extra stuff doesn't matter.  It will also skip spaces, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: just to clarify, does it also skip blank space chars, I tried using it and it didn't look right but perhaps I did it wrong...

Comment: @P.S.: Yes, it skips any character that is defined as whitespace by you current locale.  That invariably includes space, tab, carriage return, and newline, and may include other things (eg unicode spaces of various types in UTF-8 locales)

Answer (score 1):

sscanf() is really slow.  In ascii, tabs and spaces are all < '0', so you can do this:

```
char* sz = "123456789 \t 12345 \t6789\n"
char* aNum[10] = { 0 };
int cNum = 0;
for (int i=0 ; sz[i] ; ++i) {
  if (sz[i] < '0')
    sz[i] = 0, cNum++;
  else if (!aNum[cNum])
      aNum[cNum] = sz + i;
}
```

You could make this more efficient with more loops

```
char* sz = "123456789 \t 12345 \t6789\n"
char* aNum[10] = { 0 };
int cNum = 0;
for (int i=0 ; sz[i] ; ++i) {
  if (sz[i] >= '0') {
      aNum[cNum++] = sz + i;
      for ( ; sz[i]>='0' ; ++i) { }
      sz[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: "sscanf() is really slow" depends on many factors.  Advanced compilers will analyze static format strings like `"%d%d%d"` and form, at compile time, very efficient call to `strtoi()`

Comment: I can't wait till my compiler starts doing that!  One thing...strtoi is not necessarily efficient.